# How to assign value from a JSON object to an Input Type TIME?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, dom

I'm trying to assign a value to a time object, but the value is not reflected in the time input, how can I do it?

I try:

```
<input type="time" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inicioEdicao" placeholder="08:00">
 
$("#inicioEdicao").val(response.Object.Hora);
```

Comment: What is `response.Object.Hora`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example